# Новый абзац: стилистика

Tags: стилистика, абзац

1. Можно ли в новом абзаце местоимением ссылаться на слово из предыдущего? Или корректнее повторить нужное слово?

> …Вымокшие до нитки хозяева. Наталья поспешно закрыла книгу и отошла от окна.
>
> Оно пугало её: не так давно Антон выбил крепление и теперь старые створки в любой момент могли распахнуться и впустить в уютный дом бушующую стихию. <...>

2. Можно ли в абзаце местоимением ссылаться на слово из подзаголовка? Или корректнее повторить нужное слово?

> Лидерские качества
>
> На них начальник обязательно будет смотреть при выборе кандидата на повышение. <...>

3. Можно ли начинать абзац с союза?

> Упоминайте о помощи коллегам, если таковая была. Таким образом, все ваши старания будут учтены.
>
> Однако имейте в виду, что начальник обычно имеет лишь примерное представление о том, чем вы занимаетесь, и уж точно не всегда помнит, какие задачи вам были поставлены. <...>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В толковом словаре Ожегова обозначено очень просто:
[абзац](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/2522/%D0%90%D0%91%D0%97%D0%90%D0%A6), -а, муж.
**1.** Красная строка, отступ в начале строки. *Начать писать с абзаца.*
**2.** Текст между двумя такими отступами. *Прочесть первый абзац.*

И всё.
Как правило, абзац (как часть текста) включает в себя несколько предложений (фраз), но в некоторых случаях он может состоять и из одного предложения ([**А. П. Чехов. Каштанка**](http://www.c-ekb.ru/indexacf5.php)).

> Прошел месяц.
> Каштанка уже привыкла к тому, что ее каждый вечер кормили вкусным обедом и звали Теткой.

Вполне художественно местоимением ссылаться на слово из предыдущего абзаца [там же].

> Кот поднялся, лениво потянулся и нехотя, точно делая одолжение, подошел к свинье.
> — Ну-с, начнем с египетской пирамиды, — начал **хозяин.**
> **Он** долго объяснял что-то, потом скомандовал: "Раз... два... три!"

Совершенно не возбраняется начинать абзац с союза. Вот несколько начал.

> **Или** же он впадал в добродушный тон, подзывал к себе Каштанку и говорил ей...
> **Когда** он разговаривал с нею таким образом, вдруг загремела музыка.
> **Но** она ни о чем не думала и только плакала.
> **Когда** хозяин вышел и унес с собою свет, опять наступили потемки.

Теперь второй вопрос. Мне кажется, что он больше относится к оформлению списков. Если имеется в виду официальный документ, то стоит, думаю, придерживаться строгого стиля — *с повторением.*

В качестве примера ([справочник Розенталя](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xx.html)):
XX. Знаки препинания в конце предложения и при перерыве речи
§ 78. *Многоточие*

1. *Многоточие* ставится для обозначения незаконченности высказывания...
2. *Многоточие* в начале текста указывает, что продолжается...

Если же имеются в виду рекомендации или советы, оформленные в свободной (менее строгой) форме, то такое написание считаю возможным. В качестве варианта:

Что влияет на выбор руководства?

1. Лидерские качества
   На них начальник обязательно будет смотреть при выборе кандидата на повышение...
2. Образование
   Предпочтение отдается выпускникам профильных вузов и...

Answer (score 3):

Никаких правил, запрещающих разбиение на абзацы между двумя какими-либо предложениями, не существует. В художественной литературе, публицистике подобные вашим примерам приемы используют часто:

> Маргулиес сидит с Шурой Солдатовой на скамеечке возле отеля.
>
> Они ждут, когда откроется столовая. (Катаев)

---

> Были очень живы, но от смешанности и текучести "дела" из них не
>   выходило.
>
> Однако они были нужны: они выделили из себя другие кружки, более тесные, где уже стало возможным выяснить главную линию движения... (Гиппиус)

В деловой литературе неоднозначных разбиений избегают, так как документ должен быть максимально недвусмысленным.

Comment: Спасибо) Добавьте, пожалуйста, ответ на вопрос под номером два.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке нет никаких стилистических правил, которые бы ограничивали автора при распределении слов между абзацами. Небольшое отступление: в работе "Как писать книги" Стивен Кинг хорошо писал теорию абзаца: на него приходится одна тема; как только она заканчивается, начинается новый абзац.

А теперь к вопросам.

> Можно ли в новом абзаце местоимением ссылаться на слово из предыдущего? Или корректнее повторить нужное слово?

Можно! Вам никто это не запретит. Более того, если речь идёт о стилистике, то чем реже Вы будете употреблять одно и то же слово (включая однокоренные), тем Ваш текст будет симпатичнее и богаче. Вы противопоставили местоимение "тому же слову", но есть отличное стилистическое решение: замена в следующем абзаце "того же слова" на синоним. "Маша" — на "девочка", "гидра" — на "чудовище" и т.д.

Если же вопрос поставить строго — то да, можете употреблять местоимение свободно, при соблюдении двух условий:

1) В художественных текстах: слово, которое заменили местоимением, легко определить (если нет цели намерено затуманить смысл фразы).

2) В документах: если не создаётся двусмысленности (или "трёхсмысленности", и так по нарастающей).

> Можно ли в абзаце местоимением ссылаться на слово из подзаголовка? Или корректнее повторить нужное слово?

Корректнее перестроить фразу так, чтобы одинаковые слова располагались на максимально возможном расстоянии друг от друга. При необходимости, само собой, можно слово из подзаголовка заменить местоимением. Вы ведь не для роботов пишите, а для людей. Любой разумный человек способен сложить 2+2 и понять, что речь в начале текста о том, что упомянуто в подзаголовке. Грубо говоря, если статья, названая "Чарли Чаплин", начинается с фразы "Он родился в таком-то году", у меня не возникнет сомнения, что речь именно об этом актёре.

Но всё это довольно скучные ситуации, присущие текстам с духом формализма. Ничто ведь не мешает начать статью как-то интереснее: "В таком-то году, в таком-то населённом пункте родился мальчик, как вы уже догадались — герой этой статьи". Мы ведь о стиле сейчас говорим. А стиль — это не математика. Тут нужна изобретательность и изящные решения.

> Можно ли начинать абзац с союза?

С цифры, с союза, с любого слова, с какого душа пожелает, можно начинать абзац. Лишь бы фраза получилась не кривая. Даже в документах можно начать фразу с союза. Можно было бы сказать, что нельзя начать разве что с точки или запятой, но художественная литература, если понадобится, может себе позволить любые решения, если это как-то соответствует авторскому замыслу. Но это уже будут вопросы не русского языка, а искусства.